# Android ActionBar custom view hides ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in the `ActionBar`. My action bar also has a custom view on it. The draw toggle and custom view both appear on `KitKat (4.4) API 19`

However, on lower versions (for example `4.1 API 16`), the custom view in my action bar completely obscures the drawer toggle.

Working fine on 4.4 (Google Nexus 5):
[image]

How it looks on 4.1 (Google Nexus 4) (Notice the drawer missing on the left):
[image]

Wondering what can I do in this situation? Has anyone encountered this problem?

(Please note: I am not using actionbar sherlock, just the default one)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it works for me

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("yourcolor here"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        // getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer);
        // navigation icon on actionbar
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(null);
        View actionBarView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom_layout, null);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarView);
```